# Logs when importing a gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

My gradle project won't import in intellij-idea after upgrading to the latest 13.03 version.

Is there a way to get the logs produced by gradle like when doing `gradle --debug` ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gradle messages would be in IntelliJ log.

Mac OS X:

`~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea13`

Other platforms:

[Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs)

If default log level (`INFO`) is not enough to identify the issue, you can try to change the priority level.

`/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 EAP.app/bin/log.xml`

Update `<priority value="INFO"/>` to `<priority value="DEBUG"/>`

Comment: Actually I tried this but can't find the gradle logs in the intellij logs. intellij becomes more chatty but gradle remains mute.

Answer (score 0):

What is the gradle version defined in your project.
I am using idea 13.02 and Idea refuse to load project with gradle <1.9
I also have issue with the 1.11 release
So I use the wrapper with gradle 1.10

Comment: I tried the same as you :). Issue with 1.11, so tried with 1.10 but it's not working. It's under windows.

Comment: I am using linux, but this should be the same.  
  do you have this in your 'build.gradle'  
_
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion "1.10"
}
_  
Then run _#grade wrapper_
Then import the project in Idea, by selecting the wrapper.  
That's how I operate.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle daemon puts logs to `~/.gradle/daemon/<version>/daemon-<pid>.out.log`.

Full logs from IntelliJ IDEA gradle imports are stored in that directory.